# Python Dataframe select last n rows based on present value condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe. I want to select last n (=2) rows if present value is `True`.

My code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[10,20,30,40,50,60],'B':[False,False,True,False,True,False]})
    A      B
0  10  False
1  20  False
2  30   True   # Here, I should select 30,20
3  40  False
4  50   True   # Here, I should select 50,40
5  60  False

cl_id = df.columns.tolist().index('B')  ### cl_id for index number of the column for using in .iloc 
op = [df['A'].iloc[x+1-n:x+1,cl_id] if all(df['B'].iloc[x]) for x in np.arange(2,len(df))]
```

The code gave error saying `invalid syntax`
I want to select last 2 values in column A if column B value is True
My expected output:

```
opdf = 
    A      B
1  20  False
2  30   True   # Here, I should select 30,20
3  40  False
4  50   True   # Here, I should select 50,40
```

Comment: I actually expecting the dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try `limit` with `bfill`

```
n = 2
df[df.B.where(df.B).bfill(limit=n-1)==1]
Out[95]: 
    A      B
1  20  False
2  30   True
3  40  False
4  50   True
```

Comment: Neat. I definitely would have come up with the `shift` approach, but this generalizes better.

Comment: Can you look into a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63734286/python-dataframe-set-true-if-last-n-rows-are-true

Answer (score 2):

Slice with the the Boolean Series or the shifted Boolean Series to get the previous row.

```
df.loc[df['B'] | df['B'].shift(-1).fillna(False)]
    A      B
1  20  False
2  30   True
3  40  False
4  50   True
```

---

For arbitrary previous rows BEN_YO's solution is nicer. But we can make the mask using `np.logical_or.reduce`

```
import numpy as np

N = 1  # Number of previous rows
m = np.logical_or.reduce([df['B'].shift(-i).fillna(False) for i in range(N+1)])
df.loc[m]
```

Comment: can we select any number of previous rows? I mean, using a `n`. In this case, n = 2.