# Python Dataframe Set True if last n rows are True

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to create a new column where in, True if last n rows are True in other column. It is running perfectly as I wanted. The problem is it is taking lot of time.

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame({'A':[False,False,False,False,True,True,True,True,False,True]}) 
n=2 ## n to cover 10 min range samples 
cl_id = dfx.columns.tolist().index('A')  ### cl_id for index number of the column for using in .iloc 
l1=[False]*n+[all(dfx.iloc[x+1-n:x+1,cl_id].tolist()) for x in np.arange(n,len(dfx))]
dfx['B'] = l1
print(dfx)
   #old_col   # New_col
       A      B
0  False  False
1  False  False
2  False  False
3  False  False
4   True  False
5   True   True  ## Here A col last two rows True, hence True
6   True   True  ## Here A col last two rows True, hence True
7   True   True  ## Here A col last two rows True, hence True
8  False  False
9   True  False
```

Is there a better way of doing it. It is taking lot of time to run and provide the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pandas.Series.rolling`:

```
n = 2
dfx["A"].rolling(n).sum().eq(n)
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
8    False
9    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Benchmark against OP (about 1000x faster):

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame({'A':[False,False,False,False,True,True,True,True,False,True]*1000}) 

%timeit -n10 l1 = dfx["A"].rolling(n).sum().eq(n)
# 702 µs ± 88.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit -n10 l2 = [False]*n+[all(dfx.iloc[x+1-n:x+1,cl_id].tolist()) for x in np.arange(n,len(dfx))]
# 908 ms ± 24 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

l1.tolist() == l2
# True
```

Comment: Wow. This looks more elegant and a Pythonic way. It is like working on dataframe, not list.

Comment: here how do we use for last n rows ?

Comment: Wow. You are right. It gave me the answer within a second. Just like that. Previously it took me more than 5 min.